# Overwrite a Combobox style in an ItemTemplate to get rid of the focus grabbing

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, combobox, focus

Let's have a TextBox which purpose is to

- open a ComboBox if it is not already opened
- instantly filter the content of the ComboBox

It works a bit, but the problem is the ComboBox gets the focus when I hover on it with my mouse, triggering the loss of the focus for the TextBox, which is annoying.

I searched a bit and I would like to set "isEnabled" property to false, in all the ComboboxItems.
But the ComboBox already has a style, and I would rather avoid to change it; moreover I did not manage overwriting the ComboBox style.

Here is the ComboBox xaml:

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource FloatingComboBox}" IsEnabled="{Binding AdjustmentTimeCauseIsEnabled}" ItemsSource="{Binding FuneralHomes}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedFuneralHome}" IsDropDownOpen="{Binding IsFuneralHomesComboOpen}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="0,0,15,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Blue" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="|" Foreground="Black" Margin="5,0,0,0" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Address}" Margin="5,0,0,0" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

thank you.